# Call function in PostgreSQL with all parameters from a query result

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

I have a stored procedure that requires a few parameters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION USP_GET_FAID(IN "IN_metricsId"   TEXT,
                                    IN "IN_shop"        TEXT,
                                    IN "IN_shopUserId"  TEXT,
                                    IN "IN_session"     TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
                                    IN "IN_ipHash"      TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
                                    IN "IN_shopSession" TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
                                    IN "IN_userAgent"   TEXT DEFAULT NULL) 
RETURNS INT8 AS $$
```

I'd like to call this stored procedure and to provide the parameters through the results of a SELECT query, so the Stored Procedure would run for each of the lines.
I don't care about what the function returns, so it can be ignored.

How is it possible to do it (if at all)?

Comment: What does the function return? Can you show us the *complete* function definition? Btw: using quoted identifiers is almost always a bad choice. They are much more trouble in the long run then they are worth it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks - fixed. And why using quoted identifiers is a bad choice?

Comment: Because they become case-sensitive.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but otherwise it lowercases everything... if I use metricsId without, it'll be written as metricsid into the database.

Comment: Believe me: trying to use CamelCase is usually not a good idea: Use `metrics_id` instead (You can still write `Metrics_ID` if you want to). But if you insist on typing all those double quotes **all the time**, then I won't stop you - my experience is, that this usually has no benefit at all, but a lot of (hidden) problems in the long run.

Answer (score 4):

If the function only returns a single value and the parameters all come from a select statement, you can simply call it inside the select list:

```
select shop_id, usp_get_faid(metrics_id, shop, shop_id, shop_user_id, session, ip_hash, shop_session, user_agen)
from session_table
```

This assumes that all those columns are part of the `session_table` table.

Comment: OP doesn't care (ignores) the results, so this should be safe even if the function returns multiple values.

Comment: Be careful with non `VOLATILE` functions. They may be optimized away. Also you may need to fetch all results of the query

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko: Good point. Since this function is all about "side effects", it *has* to be `VOLATILE` to begin with (which is the default anyway).

Answer (score 1):

If all your input parameters come from a **single table**, you can simplify and just pass a single row type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION usp_get_faid(_tbl my_tbl) 
  RETURNS int8 AS ...
```

Then:

```
SELECT usp_get_faid(t) FROM my_tbl t WHERE my_tbl_id = 123;
```

Doesn't matter if the table contains a few extra columns that are not actually needed in the function. Just use what you need ...

This actually works for *any* combination of columns, but you need a registered row type, and there is a row type registered for every table automatically.